# How to pass parameters to spring webflow

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am working on spring webflows. I have two webflows in my application, one to add a person details and one to modify the person details. Both flows are working fine. Now I would like to pass parameter(s) to my modify flow and access it, so that I can preselect some of the values based on the passed parameter. How can I achieve it for below mentioned scenarios?

1. From the Add flow end state.
2. From outside the flow i.e from anywhere in the application except add flow.

Comment: `<end-state/>` has an [output element](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#output-element).

Comment: For the other scenario, you have to be more specific. Have you read the [Webflow documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.x/reference/htmlsingle)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. In the end it was very simple and i just had to pass the parameters in url and get the parameters that I pass using input tag in the flow.xml. Earlier i wasn't using the input tag.

Url will be something like ths

```
http://localhost:8080/modifyPerson?personName=xxx
```

Then in flow.xml personName parameter that is passed is retrieved using input tag and set to the model.

```
 <input name="personName"/>

 <view-state id="modifyBasics" view="modifyBasics" model = "person">
    <on-render>
        <set name="person.personName" value="personName"></set>
    </on-render>
    ....
 </view-state>
```

Comment: i am trying to achieve same thing but iam not been able to add parameter in URL. please help me out on this