# Put a request parameter in the url and pass it using Spring Webflow

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I'm working with spring webflow and I need to generate a requestParameter in my first flow, put and pass it in the url to the next flows.

For example:

```
http://myHost/flow1?_flowExecutionKey=e1s1&personName=Anne  
http://myHost/flow2?_flowExecutionKey=e2s2&personName=Anne  
http://myHost/flow3?_flowExecutionKey=e3s3&personName=Anne
```

Is it possible to use URL with parameters in Spring WebFLow? How can I put it in the url? How can I persist the value and pass it to the next flow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Spring Webflow passes HTTP GET params via the the 'input' tag.

see: [How to pass parameters to spring webflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008043/how-to-pass-parameters-to-spring-webflow)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<evaluate expression="myService.myFunction(requestParameters.id, flowDTO)"></evaluate>
```

This will call a myFunction from mySerivce, now in that function you can set the value in the flowDTO

```
flowDTO.setId(id);
```

To use this in the next flow you can access id field of the flow DTO in HTML page using:

```
"${flowDTO.id}"
```